# how to toggle a multiple menu in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to succeed in making a tab of a menu. when you click on one of the buttons it removes the content of the others and shows its content. When you click on it again, its content disappears, its on this last part that I have difficulties

if you have some recomandation or solution

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="tab-button" href="#content1">tab#01</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab-button" href="#content2">tab#02</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab-button" href="#content3">tab#03</a></li>

</ul>   
    
<div class="tab-content hide" id="content1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content hide" id="content2">           
    <p>Erat eu finibus. Maecenas finibus </p>
</div>                  
<div class="tab-content hide" id="content3">           
    <p>Curabitur pellentesque, dui non varius accumsan, .</p>           
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    
    .hide{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    

let links = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-button");
for(let i=0; i< links.length; i++){
  let link = links[i];
  link.addEventListener("click", (e) =>{

let content = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content');
for(let i=0; i< content.length; i++){
  content[i].classList.add('hide');
}

  let href = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
  let activeTab = document.querySelector(href);
  activeTab.classList.remove('hide');

  });
}


</script>
```

Comment: What is your expected output please ?

Answer (score 0):

ok so here is something you need.

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-button");

// loop through all the links
links.forEach(l => {
  // add click listeners
  l.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let currentTab = document.querySelector(`.tab-content${l.href.substr(l.href.indexOf("#"))}`);
    
    if(currentTab.classList.contains("hide")){
      // add hide class to all the tab content
      document.querySelectorAll(".tab-content").forEach(t => {
        t.classList.add("hide");
      });
      // remove hide class from the tab content which's id matches with the current href
      currentTab.classList.remove("hide");
    }else{
     // add hide class to all the tab content
      document.querySelectorAll(".tab-content").forEach(t => {
        t.classList.add("hide");
      });
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.hide{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="tab-button" href="#content1">tab#01</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab-button" href="#content2">tab#02</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab-button" href="#content3">tab#03</a></li>

</ul>   
    
<div class="tab-content hide" id="content1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
</div>
<div class="tab-content hide" id="content2">           
    <p>Erat eu finibus. Maecenas finibus </p>
</div>                  
<div class="tab-content hide" id="content3">           
    <p>Curabitur pellentesque, dui non varius accumsan, .</p>           
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly...

```js
const tabButtons  = document.getElementById('tab-buttons')
  ,   allContents = document.getElementById('all-contents')
  ;
tabButtons.onclick=e=>
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('li[data-content]')) return

  let onContent = e.target.dataset.content

  if ( allContents.className===onContent ) allContents.className = ''
  else allContents.className = onContent
  }
```

```css
ul#tab-buttons { cursor: pointer ;}
section#all-contents > div { display: none; }

section#all-contents.content1 > div#content1,
section#all-contents.content2 > div#content2,
section#all-contents.content3 > div#content3 { display: block; }
```

```html
<ul id="tab-buttons">
  <li data-content="content1"> tab#01 </li>
  <li data-content="content2"> tab#02 </li>
  <li data-content="content3"> tab#03 </li>
</ul>

<section id="all-contents" >
  <div id="content1">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
    <p>Erat eu finibus. Maecenas finibus </p>
  </div>
  <div id="content3">
    <p>Curabitur pellentesque, dui non varius accumsan, .</p>
  </div>    
</section>
```